# When I use insertrow, does it add row to the table or the tbody tag?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am using this Script to insert row to HTML table. I use `table.insert` because I do want to keep the original row in the HTML page, but just want to add further rows.

The table contains a tag `<tbody>`. I do the `insertrow` function at the end, which element I should call - `table` or `tbody`? In other words, is the code below, for adding rows dynamically, correct?

Script:

```
  var addButton=document.getElementById("add-button");
    addButton.addEventListener('click', addRow, false);

     function addRow(){
      event.preventDefault();

      var newData= document.getElementById("inputname").value;
      var newLevel = document.getElementById("inputlevel").value;

      console.log("new data "+newData);
      console.log("new level "+newLevel);

      var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
      var tableLength = (table.rows.length)-1;
      console.log("table lenght: "+tableLength);

      var htmltext= "<tr id= 'row"+tableLength+"'> <td id='inputname"+tableLength+"'>"+newData+"</td> \
      <td id='inputlevel"+tableLength+"'>"+newLevel+"</td>\
      <td><input type='button' id='edit-button"+tableLength+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='editRow("+tableLength+")'> \
        <input type='button' id='save-button"+tableLength+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='saveRow("+tableLength+")'> \
        <input type='button' id= 'delete-button"+tableLength+"' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='deleteRow("+tableLength+")'>\
      </td>\
 </tr>";

      table.insertRow(tableLength).innerHTML=htmltext;

    }//end addRow
```

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body id="body">

    <div id="wrapper">
        <table align='center' cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="mytable" border=1>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="inputname"></td>

                <td>
                    <select name="levels-list" id="inputlevel">
                    <option value="High" id="option-1">High</option>
                    <option value="Mid" id="option-2">Mid</option>
                    <option value="Low" id="option-3">Low</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input type="button" class="add" id="add-button" value="Add"></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  <!--  <button onclick='display()'> Display</button> -->
    <script src="get-text.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [`.insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertrow) is a method of a `table`, and you're adding a table row in a table row which would be invalid markup. Get the row you want to copy, clone it with [`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and append the clone to the `tbody`

Comment: No, the generated table is valid, i test it with chrome.

That´s not the nicest way to generate an table...

Comment: @Frank Wisniewski can you give me links on what is the nicest way

Comment: Search for document.createElement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the `table` is ok. Also you can use `createTextNode(text)` method before you insert. Check out the snippet and view [the docs on MDN (HTMLTableElement.insertRow())](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertrow) for further reading:

```js
function addRow(tableID, text) {
  // Get a reference to the table
  var tableRef = document.getElementById(tableID);

  // Insert a row in the table
  var newRow = tableRef.insertRow();

  // Insert a cell in the row
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell();

  // Append a text node to the cell
  var newText = document.createTextNode(text);
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}

// Call addRow(text) with the ID of a table
addRow('TableA', 'Brand new row');
addRow('TableA', 'Another new row');
```

```html
<table id="TableA" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1. Old top row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2. second row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```